# Simplifying exponential terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-sum

How would I simplify the following equation to solve for $x$?

$$
\frac{\exp(\frac{1-x}{20}) + \exp(\frac{10-x}{20})}
     {\exp(\frac{1-x}{5}) + \exp(\frac{10-x}{5})} = 4
$$

What about if there were additional terms in each sum, i.e.

$$
\frac{\exp(\frac{1-x}{20}) + \exp(\frac{10-x}{20}) + \exp(\frac{20-x}{20})}
     {\exp(\frac{1-x}{5}) + \exp(\frac{10-x}{5}) + \exp(\frac{20-x}{5})} = 4
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
\exp\left(\frac{1-x}{20}\right) = \frac{e^{1/20}}{e^{x/20}}
$$
so the numerator will simplify to expressions involving $e^{x/20}$, and the numerator will be in terms of $e^{x/5}$. Note that if we let $u = e^{x/20}$ then $e^{x/5} = \left(e^{x/20}\right)^4 = u^4$ and now plug in and simplify.

Comment: Thank you! this did it :)